# Full Calendar IO implementing columns into a single day view

Tags: fullcalendar

Good morning, i've been struggling with fullCalendar.io for a few days trying to implement custom views and i've gone too far with code that is incorrect so i've rolled back and I have the calendar working correctly and it's purely a visual issue i'm trying to resolve.

For a single day I am showing events from multiple staff and would like to split the single day into columns. Where might you tackle something like that in fullCalendar without going down the custom view route?

The calendar is already displaying the events but they look like https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5b0d30e471191c2f25ff2049/5ddbdf0f8d817e8937371471/07bfbc1c1593c6a019bdca59827b4bc3/image.png and it would be clearer if I could get a heading on each column and display them appropriately. The problem is some staff may have gaps in their day but the calendar fills those gaps.

Comment: "For a single day I am showing events from multiple staff"... this is a perfect use case for resource-aware view. e.g. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view. Be aware that this is a premium product though so depending on how you are going to use it in your live environment, you may need to pay fullCalendar a license fee. See https://fullcalendar.io/license and https://fullcalendar.io/license/premium

Comment: Thanks very much as I dived deeper into the docs i did find the premium views and you are right they do what I need. We will definitely purchase a licence as the product is working so well for us already. If you want to post as an answer i'll accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned:

> For a single day I am showing events from multiple staff...

This is a perfect use case for *resource-aware* view such as the [vertical resource view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view) which will create exactly the kind of display you're describing.

Be aware that this is a premium product though so depending on how you are going to use it in your live environment, you may need to pay fullCalendar a license fee. See https://fullcalendar.io/license and https://fullcalendar.io/license/premium for further details of the circumstances when you need to get a paid license, and what the costs are.